# is there way to check and unchecked the "check-boxes" from my example?

Tags: javascript, react-native, checkbox, element, react-hooks

this is my example that I try to check and unchecked the  "check-boxes" but I get confused and i will be happy if someone shows me how it should be done.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements';

const NewPlaceScreen = props => {
 const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);


 return (
     <View>
         <CheckBox
             iconRight
             right
             title="apple"
             checked={checked}
             onPress={() => setChecked(true)}
         />
         <CheckBox
             iconRight
             right
             title="kiwi"
             checked={checked}
             onPress={() => setChecked(true)}
         />
     </View>
 );

};

NewPlaceScreen.navigationOptions = {
 headerTitle: 'viewsqq'
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 TextStyle: {
     fontWeight: 'bold',
     color: 'grey'

 }
});

export default NewPlaceScreen
```

thats my example above

Answer (score 2):

You need to set them to the opposite of their previous state when pressed. You can do this by using the setState callback:

```
onPress={() => setChecked(prev => !prev)}
```

At the moment your check boxes are both using the same state variable `checked` so they will stay in sync - changing one will change the other. If this is not what you want, you should create a separate state variable for each checkbox.

---

UPDATE:

To treat each checkbox independently, you need to create state for each checkbox:

```
const [isAppleChecked, setIsAppleChecked] = useState(false)
const [isKiwiChecked, setIsKiwiChecked] = useState(false)

return (
  <View>
    <CheckBox
      iconRight
      right
      title="apple"
      checked={isAppleChecked}
      onPress={() => setIsAppleChecked(prev => !prev)}
    />
    <CheckBox
      iconRight
      right
      title="kiwi"
      checked={isKiwiChecked}
      onPress={() => setIsKiwiChecked(prev => !prev)}
    />
  </View>
)
```

Comment: but if i do as you said so it check and unchecked them all together ..if i want to check only the first checkbox so only it shuold be check and no all of them together.
can you show me the way ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a separate state for each box, otherwise they will always show the same thing. And you need to set the new state to the opposite of the old state:

```
const NewPlaceScreen = props => {
  const [appleChecked, setAppleChecked] = useState(false);
  const [kiwiChecked, setKiwiChecked] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View>
      <CheckBox
        iconRight
        right
        title='apple'
        checked={appleChecked} // use the apple-specific state
        onPress={() => setAppleChecked(prevState => !prevState)} // use the new apple state function
      />
      <CheckBox
        iconRight
        right
        title='kiwi'
        checked={kiwiChecked} // use the new kiwi state
        onPress={() => setKiwiChecked(prevState => !prevState)} // use the new kiwi function
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: You shouldn't refer to current state when setting `setAppleChecked`. If new state depends on previous state, use the setState callback.

Comment: I think it's alright. This is what the examples show in the official docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: Sorry I mean you should be passing a function to setState, not passing an object. React batches state updates, so the state may have changed by the time React actually tries to update it, meaning the state you're passing in is stale. Please read the docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: For some reason the examples in the official docs that you have linked to do not take into account this problem. I have no idea why, but the docs I have linked to do account for it and explicitly state not to do it. If I have one set of docs using the current state without any mention of pitfalls it could have, and another set of docs explicitly stating the pitfalls and showing how to avoid them, I would trust the latter.

Comment: You're right... seems like this is a better practice. I guess the docs I linked to are an intro to state hooks so they want to keep it simple? Still, if it's wrong then they should update it ^^

Comment: I totally agree. I don't see how they can forego best practice, or indeed, correct practice, just to "keep things simple". The docs need updating.