# is there way to check/uncheck a circle button as my example?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

how I can check/uncheck the circle button as my example?
this is the example that i trying to understand

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements';


const NewPlaceScreen = props => {
    return (
        <View>
            <CheckBox
                iconRight
                right
                title='poshea'
                checkedIcon='dot-circle-o'
                uncheckedIcon='circle-o'
                onPress={() => setChecked6(prev => !prev)}
            />
            <CheckBox
                iconRight
                right
                title='oshea'
                checkedIcon='dot-circle-o'
                uncheckedIcon='circle-o'
                checked={() => setChecked7(prev => !prev)}
            />
        </View>
    );

};

NewPlaceScreen.navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: 'wiki'
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    TextStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: 'grey'
    }
});

export default NewPlaceScreen
```

if there is some clue to show me the way to understand?
the example is above

Comment: You've mixed up `checked` and `onPress`. `checked` is going to be true or false, and needs to refer some state. In this example you need to create two state variables `checked6` and `checked7` in the same way we discussed in your other question[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59550755/is-there-way-to-check-and-unchecked-the-check-boxes-from-my-example/59550803#59550803]. Then assign those two values to your `checked` props. `onPress` is correct in this case for your first checkbox, once you add in state at the top of the component

Answer (score 0):

```
const NewPlaceScreen = props => {
  const [selectedCheckbox, setSelectedCheckbox] = useState(null);

  const handlePress = title => {
    selectedCheckbox === title ? setSelectedCheckbox(null) : setSelectedCheckbox(title)
  }

  ...

}
```

Example for `CheckBox` component

```
  <CheckBox
    iconRight
    right
    title='oshea'
    checkedIcon='dot-circle-o'
    uncheckedIcon='circle-o'
    checked={selectedCheckbox === 'oshea'}
    onPress={() => handlePress('oshea'))}
  />
```

Comment: if i want to check only one of them when i press for example:
if i will press the checkicon 1 and after i press also the  checkicon 2 so it let me check the 2 and clear the others.
it's mean that when you choose one of the checkicons so oly it will be checked and the other not.